# undefined React JS variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, undefined, jsx

this is my first time coding in Javascript/React JS so I'm not sure what is wrong here. getLicensees() send a GET request it my API and returns all the licensees. This works so far, also the console logs are working and printing the correct value.

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {licensees: []};

let licenseeResponse = LicensingService.getLicensees()
  .then(licensees => {
    this.state.licensees = licensees;
    console.log("component", licensees);
    console.log(licensees[0].city);
  });
}
```

I'm trying to generate a table out of all the information’s inside my licensees object. But I can’t use `this.state.licensees[0].city` inside my render() method.

```
render() {
return (
  <main id="content">
    <div id="head">
      <h4 className="headline">
        Liste aller Lizenznehmer
      </h4>

      <div className="licenseeTable">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Lizenz nehmer</th>
            <th>Aktuelles Zertifikat</th>
            <th>Details</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>{this.state.licensees[0].city}</td>
            <td>test2</td>
            <td>test3</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
);
}
```

how can I do this properly?

--My solution:

```
componentDidMount() {
console.log('component did mount..', this);
LicensingService.getLicensees()
  .then(licensees => {
    this.setState({licensees});
    console.log(licensees);
  });
}
```

...

```
{
            this.state.licensees.map(license => {
              return <tr>
                <td>{license.company}</td>
                <td>{license.testCertificate.toString()}</td>
                <td>{license.city}</td>
              </tr>
            })
          }
```

this.setState({licensees}) is the correct way to assign value to the state object.

Comment: *Offtopic : You might want to look at the official docs, I think there is a minor  issue in your set state logic, https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html, although the state in React is an object and it's ok to set it directly in the constructor, it's more appropriate to use the `setState` method outside the constructor (for exmaple in the `componentDidMount` hook) when fetching some data (i assume `getLicensees` is some async code)

Comment: Have you changed your setState to this `this.setState({licensees});` ??

Comment: yes I have :--)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that although you have your API request in constructor, it will return a response only after the render cycle and since you are directly mutating state in the resolved promise, a re-render is not called.

What you need to do is to have the API call in `componentDidMount` lifecycle method and update your state using setState

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);

   this.state = {licensees: []};

}

componentDidMount() {
    LicensingService.getLicensees()
      .then(licensees => {
        this.setState({licensees});
        console.log("component", licensees);
        console.log(licensees[0].city);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This helps me :)

Comment: Glad to have helped :-)

Comment: but there is another problem, he’s saying that:
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {city, ...} . If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

I tried to form it into an array but it’s says it can’t do it because its undefined

I tried to form it into an array but its says it cant do it becouse its undefined

Comment: can you add your licences array in the question

Comment: Edit the wrong post *facepalm*, see it now on my original question :)

Comment: What I meant was for you to add the sample response for licensees

Comment: do you mean this?

Answer (score 1):

First you want to move the api call to componentDidMount instead of doing it in a constructor, doing so wont work as your component would already have rendered before you get the data.

Then you need to use `setState` to cause your render function to be called so that the updated value is displayed. like this :

`this.setState({licensees});`  instead of mutating the state directly like

```
this.state.licensees = licensees;
```

read more here [Using State Correctly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly)

You would also want to wait for the value untilll you try to access it so you will have to make this change in your render as well
Instead of this :

```
<td>{this.state.licensees[0].city}</td>
```

do this

```
{this.state.licensees && <td>{this.state.licensees[0].city}</td>} //only render when you have the value in the state.
```